# Proof of a trigonometric relation

Tags: trigonometry

In the solution of the ambiguous case for plane triangles, in which the sides $ a, b$ and angle $ A $ are given, how to prove that

$ (c+c')/2 = b\cos A $

Where $c$ and $c'$ are the corresponding sides of the two possible triangles?

Thanks for the proof. If someone like to add another, just do it.

Comment: This is actually a part of proof of proving the nonexistence of the ASS congruence. For right angled triangle, the two possible sides are equal, hence we get RHS congruency

Answer (score 1):

Let the third side be $x$.
By cosine law,
$$a^2=b^2+x^2-2bx\cos A$$
$$x^2-(2b\cos A)x+(b^2-a^2)=0$$
If 
$$b^2\cos^2 A>b^2-a^2$$
i.e.
$$a>b\sin A$$
Then there are two roots $c$ and $c'$, and
$c+c'=2b\cos A$.

Comment: $a>b \sin A $ in a $\triangle $. Why mention it?

Answer (score 0):

By law of cosines, you get the relation:

$c^2-2 \cos A c b +b^2-a^2=0$

Sum of solutions of a quadratic equation is given by :

$\frac {- \beta}{\alpha} =c'+c''$

Here it becomes $2b \cos A $

Hence $\frac {c'+c''}{2}= b \cos A $

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta $ are coefficients of a quadratic equation.